# how to click Ok on pop up in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

after I click the save button I need to click OK in pop up

[image]
I tried

alert = driver.switch_to_alert
alert.accept()

but its not working im getting an error AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'accept'

Comment: Right click and inspect element to check what html element it is.

Comment: you mean inspect the pop up?   theres no html element

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

ok_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "OK")]'))).click()
```

Comment: line 82, in <module>
    ok_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "OK")]'))).click()

Comment: copy your xpath and paste it instead of '//button[contains(text(), "OK")]'

Comment: i cant detect the element of ok button actually